# Replace a text on the same line after finding another text

Tags: sed

I have a SQL file with the following approximate structure.

```
INSERT INTO asdassd (3,_binary 'asdfsdfsdf\"/>',-1234);
INSERT INTO hfhdfghdf (1476,'ghdfsdfg','sdfgdfgsdf',-1234);
INSERT INTO retfdxfsd (1476,'xdfgthb',_binary 'nghfghgfh',-1234);
```

I need to replace the text `',` with `'),` on the lines where the word `_binary` appears, but only the first occurrence after `_binary`.

I have come up with this expression that works correctly for the first two lines but not for the third since it replaces the first occurrence of what I want to replace regardless of the position of the word `_binary`.

```
sed  -i "/_binary/{s/',/'),/}" file
```

Comment: Kindly do add sample of expected output in your question; to make it more clear, thank you.

Comment: Can `foo_binary` or `_binaryfoo` or similar appear in your input? If so how should that be handled?

Comment: only _binary appears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to include the condition in the replacement regex.

By the way, the braces in yoqr attempt were unnecessary. Also, probably don't use `-i` until you have a working script.

```
sed  -i "s/\(_binary.*\)',/\1'),/" file
```

In other words, we capture `_binary` followed by anything followed by the pattern you want to match, and replace the matching expression with the captured string followed by the replacement. `\1` is a backreference which recalls whatever text the first set of capturing parentheses matched.

Comment: sed: -e expression #1, char 25: unexpected `}'

Comment: Thank you. removing the } works.
Can you explain a little to me.

Comment: Sorry for the copy/paste error; fixed that and added an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -Ei.bak '/_binary[^,]*/s//&)/' input_file
INSERT INTO asdassd (3,_binary 'asdfsdfsdf"/>'),-1234);
INSERT INTO hfhdfghdf (1476,'ghdfsdfg','sdfgdfgsdf',-1234);
INSERT INTO retfdxfsd (1476,'xdfgthb',_binary 'nghfghgfh'),-1234);
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/_binary /{s/'\'',/\n/g;s/(_binary [^\n]*)\n/\1'\''),/;s/\n/'\'',/g}' file
```

For those lines that contain `_binary` :

Replace all occurrences of `',` with a newline.

Replace the first newline after `_binary`  with `'),`.

Replace all newlines with `',`.